# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test on project XYZ

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testng

Am using maven project for my automation suite. Am getting the below error when run my suite from Jenkins. The same suite, if run by Eclipse IDE it is working fine.

### Stack Trace Error:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ XYZ ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\test\.jenkins\workspace\proj\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ XYZ ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ XYZ ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\test\.jenkins\workspace\proj\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ XYZ ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ XYZ ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\test\.jenkins\workspace\proj\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ XYZ ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ XYZ ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\test\.jenkins\workspace\proj\target\surefire-reports
Running TestSuite
[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.557 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-16T15:12:21+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/169M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project XYZ: Exception in provider:
[ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: pch.iwe.test.TestClassxxxxx
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

### pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>XYZ</groupId>
<artifactId>XYZ</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>TEST</name>
<description>TEST</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.48.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
        <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>never</forkMode>
                <forkCount>0</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>./testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>                   
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

### Stack Trace with -X:

```
    Started by user anonymous
Building on master in workspace C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\workspace\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin_Local
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 59895
[PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73/bin/java" -cp C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven32-agent-1.7.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9 C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.59.jar C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven32-interceptor-1.7.jar C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.7.jar 59895
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\pom.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0 test -X
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T22:11:47+05:30)
Maven home: C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_73, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.m2\settings.xml
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building IWEAdmin 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-java) @ PrizeMachine ---
[DEBUG] Executing rule: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion
[DEBUG] Rule org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion is cacheable.
[DEBUG] Detected Java String: 1.8.0_73
[DEBUG] Normalized Java String: 1.8.0-73
[DEBUG] Parsed Version: Major: 1 Minor: 8 Incremental: 0 Build: 73 Qualifier: null
[DEBUG] Detected JDK Version: 1.8.0-73 is allowed in the range 1.8.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ PrizeMachine ---
[DEBUG] properties used {PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, ProgramData=C:\ProgramData, java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre, NODE_NAME=master, JENKINS_URL=http://localhost:8080/, env.LDMS_PREFERRED_SERVER=pwld1, ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData, java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\endorsed, env.POM_VERSION=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, env.USERNAME=MPERUMAL$, env.HUDSON_HOME=C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins, PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files\Citrix\Telemetry Service\, USERDOMAIN=CLASSIC, sun.os.patch.level=Service Pack 1, java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, env.COMPUTERNAME=MPERUMAL, CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files, env.NODE_NAME=master, java.version=1.8.0_73, JOB_NAME=PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin_Local, COMPUTERNAME=MPERUMAL, env.NODE_LABELS=master, env.JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE=e3de73e41634bc66, java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/, PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public, env.USERPROFILE=C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile, env.SERVICE_ID=jenkins, user.name=MPERUMAL$, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle, sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252, java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, windir=C:\Windows, env.LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local, LDMS_PREFERRED_SERVER=pwld1, PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 62 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel, env.COMMONPROGRAMW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files, java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local, user.timezone=Asia/Calcutta, user.script=, path.separator=;, NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=2, BUILD_TAG=jenkins-PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin_Local-6, env.PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 62 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel, file.encoding=Cp1252, sun.java.command=jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9 C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.59.jar C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven32-interceptor-1.7.jar C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.7.jar 59895, HUDSON_URL=http://localhost:8080/, env.NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=2, JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE=e3de73e41634bc66, env.APPDATA=C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming, EXECUTOR_NUMBER=0, Path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73/bin;%JAVA_HOME%;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Citrix\System32\;%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%JAVA_HOME%/lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Citrix\ICAService\;C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73\lib, env.WINDIR=C:\Windows, env.BUILD_TAG=jenkins-PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin_Local-6, BASE=C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins, java.io.tmpdir=C:\Windows\TEMP\, APPDATA=C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming, user.language=en, line.separator=
, maven.repo.local=C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0, BUILD_URL=http://localhost:8080/job/PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin_Local/6/, M2_HOME=C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9, env.COMMONPROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files\Common Files, env.JOB_NAME=PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin_Local, java.vm.info=mixed mode, env.BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME=#6, sun.desktop=windows, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME=#6, OS=Windows_NT, env.BUILD_URL=http://localhost:8080/job/PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin_Local/6/, env.M2_HOME=C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9, env.PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC, guice.disable.misplaced.annotation.check=true, HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE=e3de73e41634bc66, env.POM_ARTIFACTID=PrizeMachine, MAVEN_HOME=C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9, env.PSMODULEPATH=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files\Citrix\Telemetry Service\, PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC, java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob, maven3.interceptor.common=C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.7.jar, CLASSPATH=, env.HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE=e3de73e41634bc66, env.PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public, env.USERDOMAIN=CLASSIC, env.PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6, env.PROGRAMFILES(X86)=C:\Program Files (x86), env.BUILD_NUMBER=6, os.name=Windows 7, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO, env.TMP=C:\Windows\TEMP, java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, BUILD_NUMBER=6, env.JOB_URL=http://localhost:8080/job/PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin_Local/, env.OS=Windows_NT, maven3.interceptor=C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven32-interceptor-1.7.jar, java.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9/bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73/bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73/bin;%JAVA_HOME%;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Citrix\System32\;%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%JAVA_HOME%/lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Citrix\ICAService\;C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73\lib;., env.PROGRAMW6432=C:\Program Files, env.PATH=C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9/bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73/bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73/bin;%JAVA_HOME%;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Citrix\System32\;%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%JAVA_HOME%/lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Citrix\ICAService\;C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73\lib, env.HUDSON_URL=http://localhost:8080/, WINSW_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\jenkins.exe, env.JENKINS_URL=http://localhost:8080/, POM_GROUPID=PCH, POM_ARTIFACTID=PrizeMachine, java.class.version=52.0, JOB_URL=http://localhost:8080/job/PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin_Local/, env.JENKINS_HOME=C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins, env.BASE=C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins, env.SYSTEMROOT=C:\Windows, maven.compiler.testTarget=1.8, env.COMSPEC=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe, JENKINS_HOME=C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins, BUILD_ID=6, TEMP=C:\Windows\TEMP, sun.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\bin, env.SYSTEMDRIVE=C:, env.PROCESSOR_REVISION=3e04, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers, env.POM_DISPLAYNAME=IWEAdmin, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment, user.variant=, PROCESSOR_REVISION=3e04, POM_VERSION=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, maven.compiler.testSource=1.8, HUDSON_HOME=C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins, ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86), PATH+MAVEN=C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9/bin, env.PROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files, java.vm.specification.version=1.8, JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73, env.PROGRAMDATA=C:\ProgramData, awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit, NODE_LABELS=master, env.MAVEN_HOME=C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9, sun.cpu.isalist=amd64, USERPROFILE=C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile, java.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext, os.version=6.1, user.home=C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile, USERNAME=MPERUMAL$, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6, env.JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73, CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files, user.dir=C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin, env.COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files, ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files, TMP=C:\Windows\TEMP, env.FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO, sun.cpu.endian=little, env.ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData, SystemDrive=C:, env.WINSW_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\jenkins.exe, env.PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64, java.vm.version=25.73-b02, java.class.path=C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven32-agent-1.7.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9/conf/logging, org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug, os.arch=amd64, maven.build.version=Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T22:11:47+05:30), WORKSPACE=C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\workspace\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin_Local, ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe, env.POM_PACKAGING=jar, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, SERVICE_ID=jenkins, SystemRoot=C:\Windows, env.BUILD_ID=6, CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files, java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, env.LDMS_LOCAL_DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\LANDesk\LDClient\Data, file.separator=\, java.runtime.version=1.8.0_73-b02, ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files, sun.boot.class.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\classes, env.WORKSPACE=C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\workspace\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin_Local, maven.version=3.3.9, env.TEMP=C:\Windows\TEMP, PATH+JDK=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73/bin, user.country=US, env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER=0, POM_PACKAGING=jar, maven.home=C:\Users\mperumal\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9, LDMS_LOCAL_DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\LANDesk\LDClient\Data, maven.compiler.target=1.8, JOB_BASE_NAME=PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin_Local, env.JOB_BASE_NAME=PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin_Local, java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, env.POM_GROUPID=PCH, maven.compiler.source=1.8, env.HUDSON_COOKIE=27bdde2c-a0c2-430f-95f5-8b0e6149dd77, java.specification.version=1.8, POM_DISPLAYNAME=IWEAdmin, sun.arch.data.model=64}
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[DEBUG] resource with targetPath null
directory C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\src\main\resources
excludes []
includes []
[DEBUG] ignoreDelta true
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[DEBUG] file env.properties has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] copy C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\src\main\resources\config\env.properties to C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\target\classes\config\env.properties
[DEBUG] file pageurl.properties has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] copy C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\src\main\resources\config\pageurl.properties to C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\target\classes\config\pageurl.properties
[DEBUG] file chromedriver.exe has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] copy C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\src\main\resources\drivers\chromedriver.exe to C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\target\classes\drivers\chromedriver.exe
[DEBUG] file testdata.xls has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] copy C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\src\main\resources\testinput\testdata.xls to C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\target\classes\testinput\testdata.xls
[DEBUG] file write.xlsx has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] copy C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\src\main\resources\testinput\write.xlsx to C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\target\classes\testinput\write.xlsx
[DEBUG] no use filter components
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ PrizeMachine ---
[DEBUG] Using compiler 'javac'.
[DEBUG] Source directories: [C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\src\main\java]
[DEBUG] Classpath: [C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\target\classes
 C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\org\json\json\20090211\json-20090211.jar
 C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.6\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar
 C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar
 C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-all\1.3\hamcrest-all-1.3.jar
 C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\com\googlecode\lambdaj\lambdaj\2.3.3\lambdaj-2.3.3.jar
 C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\org\objenesis\objenesis\1.2\objenesis-1.2.jar
 C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\cglib\cglib-nodep\2.2\cglib-nodep-2.2.jar]
[DEBUG] Output directory: C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\target\classes
[DEBUG] Adding C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\target\generated-sources\annotations to compile source roots:
  C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\src\main\java
[DEBUG] New compile source roots:
  C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\src\main\java
  C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\target\generated-sources\annotations
[DEBUG] CompilerReuseStrategy: reuseCreated
[DEBUG] useIncrementalCompilation enabled
[DEBUG] Stale source detected: C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\src\main\java\pch\iwe\util\ConfigUtil.java
[DEBUG] Stale source detected: C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\src\main\java\pch\iwe\util\ConsolidatedHTMLReport.java
[DEBUG] Stale source detected: C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\src\main\java\pch\iwe\util\CustomListener.java
[DEBUG] Stale source detected: C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\src\main\java\pch\iwe\util\CustomLogger.java
[DEBUG] Stale source detected: C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\src\main\java\pch\iwe\util\SearchContext.java
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[DEBUG] Classpath:
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\target\classes
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\org\json\json\20090211\json-20090211.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.6\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\com\thoughtworks\xstream\xstream\1.4.2\xstream-1.4.2.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\xmlpull\xmlpull\1.1.3.1\xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\xpp3\xpp3_min\1.1.4c\xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\net\sourceforge\jexcelapi\jxl\2.6.12\jxl-2.6.12.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\log4j\log4j\1.2.14\log4j-1.2.14.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\org\apache\poi\poi\3.13\poi-3.13.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml\3.13\poi-ooxml-3.13.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml-schemas\3.13\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\org\apache\xmlbeans\xmlbeans\2.6.0\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\stax\stax-api\1.0.1\stax-api-1.0.1.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\ru\yandex\qatools\ashot\ashot\1.4.12\ashot-1.4.12.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-all\1.3\hamcrest-all-1.3.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\com\googlecode\lambdaj\lambdaj\2.3.3\lambdaj-2.3.3.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\org\objenesis\objenesis\1.2\objenesis-1.2.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\cglib\cglib-nodep\2.2\cglib-nodep-2.2.jar
[DEBUG] Source roots:
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\src\main\java
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\target\generated-sources\annotations
[DEBUG] Command line options:
[DEBUG] -d C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\target\classes -classpath C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\target\classes;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\org\json\json\20090211\json-20090211.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.6\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\com\thoughtworks\xstream\xstream\1.4.2\xstream-1.4.2.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\xmlpull\xmlpull\1.1.3.1\xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\xpp3\xpp3_min\1.1.4c\xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\net\sourceforge\jexcelapi\jxl\2.6.12\jxl-2.6.12.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\log4j\log4j\1.2.14\log4j-1.2.14.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\org\apache\poi\poi\3.13\poi-3.13.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml\3.13\poi-ooxml-3.13.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml-schemas\3.13\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\org\apache\xmlbeans\xmlbeans\2.6.0\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\stax\stax-api\1.0.1\stax-api-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\ru\yandex\qatools\ashot\ashot\1.4.12\ashot-1.4.12.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-all\1.3\hamcrest-all-1.3.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\com\googlecode\lambdaj\lambdaj\2.3.3\lambdaj-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\org\objenesis\objenesis\1.2\objenesis-1.2.jar;C:\Users\mperumal\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0\cglib\cglib-nodep\2.2\cglib-nodep-2.2.jar; -sourcepath C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\src\main\java;C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\target\generated-sources\annotations; -s C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\target\generated-sources\annotations -g -deprecation -target 1.8 -source 1.8 -source 1.8 -target 1.8
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#beforeRebuildExecution
[INFO] Compiling 19 source files to C:\Users\mperumal\Desktop\PCH_Test_WS\PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin\target\classes
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#afterRebuildExecution
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mperumal/Desktop/PCH_Test_WS/PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin/src/main/java/pch/iwe/util/SearchContext.java:[5,27] package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mperumal/Desktop/PCH_Test_WS/PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin/src/main/java/pch/iwe/util/SearchContext.java:[6,27] package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mperumal/Desktop/PCH_Test_WS/PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin/src/main/java/pch/iwe/util/SearchContext.java:[8,42] package com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mperumal/Desktop/PCH_Test_WS/PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin/src/main/java/pch/iwe/util/SearchContext.java:[22,42] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class By
  location: interface pch.iwe.util.SearchContext
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mperumal/Desktop/PCH_Test_WS/PrizeMachine_IWEAdmin/src/main/java/pch/iwe/util/SearchContext.java:[22,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HtmlElement
  location: interface pch.iwe.util.SearchContext
```

**Used Version:**
Maven : 3.3.9
JDK : 1.8.0.73
Jenkins : 2.8

Comment: please  use the -X switch to enable full debug.. and then update your quesstion.

Comment: Move the `testng.xml` to the `src/test/resources/` folder. Is it working?

Comment: @VikrantKashyap Full debug trace is too big. Hope added the needed info.

Comment: @JulienHerr It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 outputs don't show the same issue: run test failure versus compilation failure.

It seems our `SearchContext` located into `src/main/java` has a direct dependency to selenium and htmlunit but selenium is `<scope>test</scope>`.

-> You have to change the location of the class (`src/test/java`) or update the scope of your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the response Julien. Have resolved by modifying the package structure. But faced another one issue when run my build via SCM. Error: Unable to remove .svn, please close if opened.
ERROR: Maven JVM terminated unexpectedly with exit code 1

Comment: Please,  update the question with the log and/or stacktrace

Comment: Thanks for the response. Have created a separate question for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880394/unable-to-remove-svn-please-close-if-opened-jenkins. Please give your suggestion on it.