# Unable to remove .svn, please close if opened. + Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, svn, jenkins

Am getting this error when i execute the Maven project from the SVN.

### Stack Trace:

```
    Building on master in workspace C:\Users\test\.jenkins\workspace\project_SVN
Updating https://svn.dev.pch.com/svn/scripts/Testing/Automation/project at revision '2016-06-17T16:49:28.780 +0530'
At revision 2974

No changes for https://svn.dev.pch.com/svn/scripts/Testing/Automation/project since the previous build
Parsing POMs
Modules changed, recalculating dependency graph
Established TCP socket on 62160
[project_SVN] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73/bin/java" -cp C:\Users\test\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven32-agent-1.7.jar;C:\Users\test\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\test\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main C:\Users\test\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9 C:\Users\test\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.59.jar C:\Users\test\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven32-interceptor-1.7.jar C:\Users\test\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.7.jar 62160
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Users\test\.jenkins\workspace\project_SVN\pom.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=C:\Users\test\.jenkins\maven-repositories\0 clean install test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building IWEAdmin 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ SampleProject ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\test\.jenkins\workspace\project_SVN\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-java) @ SampleProject ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SampleProject ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ SampleProject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ SampleProject ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ SampleProject ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 87 source files to C:\Users\test\.jenkins\workspace\project_SVN\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ SampleProject ---
[WARNING] The parameter forkMode is deprecated since version 2.14. Use forkCount and reuseForks instead.
[WARNING] useSystemClassloader setting has no effect when not forking
Running TestSuite
...
... TestNG 6.9.10 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...

[TestRunner] Running the tests in 'Instant Win' with parallel mode:tests
[RunInfo] Adding method selector: org.testng.internal.XmlMethodSelector@66038a2c priority: 10
[TestClass] Creating TestClass for [ClassImpl class=pch.iwe.test.TestClassEGiftCard]
[TestClass] Adding method TestClassEGiftCard.verifyTabPresence()[pri:1, instance:null] on TestClass class pch.iwe.test.TestClassEGiftCard
[TestClass] Adding method TestClassEGiftCard.verifyDisplayRecords()[pri:2, instance:null] on TestClass class pch.iwe.test.TestClassEGiftCard
[XmlMethodSelector] Including method pch.iwe.test.beforeSuite()
[XmlMethodSelector] Including method pch.iwe.test.readConfigFile()
[XmlMethodSelector] Including method pch.iwe.test.closeConnections()
[XmlMethodSelector] Including method pch.iwe.test.navigateGiftCardTab()
[MethodInheritance] TestClassEGiftCard.navigateGiftCardTab()[pri:0, instance:null] DEPENDS ON BaseTest.beforeMethod(java.lang.reflect.Method, org.testng.ITestContext)[pri:0, instance:null]
[XmlMethodSelector] Including method pch.iwe.test.verifyTabPresence()
[XmlMethodSelector] Including method pch.iwe.test.verifyDisplayRecords()
[TestRunner] Running the tests in 'Instant Win Two' with parallel mode:tests
[RunInfo] Adding method selector: org.testng.internal.XmlMethodSelector@38527ecb priority: 10
Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for LOCAL_DATE_SEPARATOR - setting to empty
Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for LOCAL_DAY_FORMAT - setting to empty
Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for LOCAL_HOUR_FORMAT - setting to empty
Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for LOCAL_MINUTE_FORMAT - setting to empty
Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for LOCAL_MONTH_FORMAT - setting to empty
Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for LOCAL_MYSQL_DATE_FORMAT - setting to empty
Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for LOCAL_SECOND_FORMAT - setting to empty
Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for LOCAL_TIME_SEPARATOR - setting to empty
Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for LOCAL_YEAR_FORMAT - setting to empty
[TestClass] Creating TestClass for [ClassImpl class=pch.iwe.test.TestClassBusinessunit]
[TestClass] Adding method TestClassBusinessunit.createBusinessUnit()[pri:1, instance:null] on TestClass class pch.iwe.test.TestClassBusinessunit
[TestClass] Adding method TestClassBusinessunit.verifyTokenHistoryDisplayImage()[pri:4, instance:null] on TestClass class pch.iwe.test.TestClassBusinessunit
[TestClass] Adding method TestClassBusinessunit.updateBusinessUnit()[pri:2, instance:null] on TestClass class pch.iwe.test.TestClassBusinessunit
[TestClass] Adding method TestClassBusinessunit.verifyAuditHistory()[pri:3, instance:null] on TestClass class pch.iwe.test.TestClassBusinessunit
[XmlMethodSelector] Including method pch.iwe.test.beforeSuite()
[XmlMethodSelector] Including method pch.iwe.test.readConfigFile()
[XmlMethodSelector] Including method pch.iwe.test.closeConnections()
[XmlMethodSelector] Including method pch.iwe.test.navigateBUListPage()
[MethodInheritance] TestClassBusinessunit.navigateBUListPage()[pri:0, instance:null] DEPENDS ON BaseTest.beforeMethod(java.lang.reflect.Method, org.testng.ITestContext)[pri:0, instance:null]
[XmlMethodSelector] Including method pch.iwe.test.closeBusinessUnitEditModalWindow()
[MethodInheritance] BaseTest.afterMethod(java.lang.reflect.Method, org.testng.ITestResult, org.testng.ITestContext)[pri:0, instance:null] DEPENDS ON TestClassBusinessunit.closeBusinessUnitEditModalWindow()[pri:0, instance:null]
[XmlMethodSelector] Including method pch.iwe.test.createBusinessUnit()
[XmlMethodSelector] Including method pch.iwe.test.verifyTokenHistoryDisplayImage()
[XmlMethodSelector] Including method pch.iwe.test.updateBusinessUnit()
[XmlMethodSelector] Including method pch.iwe.test.verifyAuditHistory()
[Invoker 1747603520] Keeping method BaseTest.beforeSuite()[pri:0, instance:pch.iwe.test.TestClassBusinessunit@3aec689] for class null
[Invoker 1747603520] Invoking @BeforeSuite BaseTest.beforeSuite()[pri:0, instance:pch.iwe.test.TestClassBusinessunit@3aec689]
Unable to remove .svn, please close if opened.
ERROR: Maven JVM terminated unexpectedly with exit code 1
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level C:\Users\test\.jenkins\workspace\project_SVN\CustomHTMLReport\HTMLReports to C:\Users\test\.jenkins\jobs\project_SVN\builds\30\htmlreports\TestReport
ERROR: Directory 'C:\Users\test\.jenkins\workspace\project_SVN\CustomHTMLReport\HTMLReports' exists but failed copying to 'C:\Users\test\.jenkins\jobs\project_SVN\builds\30\htmlreports\TestReport'.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Maven: 3.3.9
JDK: 1.8.0.73
SVN: 1.6
Jenkins: 2.8

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your pom's plugin configuration:

```
<noExit>true</noExit>
<continueOnFailure>true</continueOnFailure>
```

and rebuild it. If above doesn't helps, then there is another, System.exit() somewhere in the code path. You might need to remove that. and also make sure you have increased `MAVEN_OPTS` in jenkins.

Comment: Have added the above code in the surfire plugin configuration. Added MAVEN_OPTS values as '-Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m'. Nothing sounds good.